# How can I hide a div when not hovering anymore

Tags: jquery, hover, show-hide

I am using Jquery to hide show a div. I want to show the div when '.microblogpostwrapper' is hovered and hidden when not hovered. Got the first bit done but can't get it to hide when not hovered.

```
  $(".microblogpostwrapper").hover(function(){ 
            $(this).find(".microblogpostactions").show();
                                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handler will fire once for `mouseenter` and once for `mouseleave`.

```
$(".microblogpostwrapper").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).find(".microblogpostactions").toggle(); // Toggle the show/hide
});
```

You can ensure the proper toggle is performed by passing a boolean value to [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$(".microblogpostwrapper").hover(function( e ){ 
    $(this).find(".microblogpostactions").toggle( e.type == 'mouseenter' );
});
```

Alternatively, you could pass a second function to `hover()` where you would use `.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.hover()` [binds two handlers](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), one for 'in' and another for 'out.' The following should achieve what you want (although it might be worth assigning the element you're manipulating to a variable for a slight speed improvement):

```
$(".microblogpostwrapper").hover(
    function(){ 
        $(this).find(".microblogpostactions").show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find(".microblogpostactions").hide()
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use mouseenter/mouseleave to stop bubbling (re-calling hover while mouse moving):::

```
$(".microblogpostwrapper").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".microblogpostactions").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".microblogpostactions").hide();
});​
```